# How do you compare hashes for equality that contain different key formats (some strings, some symbols) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-1.9.3

I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and I need to compare two hashes that have different key formats. For example, I want the equality of the following two hashes to be the true:

```
hash_1 = {:date => 2011-11-01, :value => 12}
hash_2 = {"date" => 2011-11-01, "value" => 12}
```

Any ideas on how these two hashes can be compared in one line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stringify the keys on the hash that has symbols:

```
 > hash_1.stringify_keys
=> {"date"=>"2011-11-01", "value"=>12}
```

Then compare. So, your answer, in one line, is:

```
 > hash_1.stringify_keys == hash_2    
=> true
```

You could also do it the other way around, symbolizing the string keys in `hash_2` instead of stringifying them in `hash_1`:

```
 > hash_1 == hash_2.symbolize_keys
=> true
```

If you want the stringification/symbolization to be a permanent change, use the version with the bang `!`: `stringify_keys!` or `symbolize_keys!` respectively

```
 > hash_1.stringify_keys!                # <- Permanently changes the keys in hash_1 into Strings
=> {"date"=>"2011-11-01", "value"=>12}   #    as opposed to temporarily changing them for comparison
```

**Ref:** http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html

Also, I'm guessing you meant to put quotes around the dates...

`:date => "2011-11-01"`

...or, explicitly instantiate them as Date objects?

`:date => Date.new("2011-11-01")`

The way you have the date written now sets `:date` to `2011-11-01` These are currently being interpreted as series of integers with subtraction in between them.

That is:

```
 > date = 2011-11-01
=> 1999                # <- integer value of 2011, minus 11, minus 1
```

Comment: Thanks very much. works perfeclty! Yes, I meant to put the dates in quotes, i.e. :date => "2011-11-01"